# How to show that if $P(A_{i}) = 1$ for all $i \geq 1$ then $P(\ \bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i)=1$

Tags: probability

Show that if $P(A_{i}) = 1$ for all $i \geq 1$ then $P(\ \bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i)=1$

Comment: Hint: Express $\bigl(\bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i\bigr)^C$ in terms of the sets $A_i^C$.

Comment: This is equivalent to $P(B_i) =0$ and $P(\cup B_i) = 0$ which you have from $B_i = A_i^c$ and de Morgan. This fact about $B_i$ follows from your previous question. But now it seems that you're doing your homework. So what have you tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have  $$P(\cap_i A_i) = 1- P(\cup_i A_i^c) \geq 1 - \sum_i P(A_i^c) = 1 - 0.$$
Thus $1 \geq P(\cap_i A_i) \geq 1$ and so $P(\cap_i A_i)=1$.